# Finding paths of fixed cost in weighted undirected graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph, computation-theory, breadth-first-search

I have the following problem and I'm not quite sure how to solve it:

Given a graph `G = (V;E)` in which every edge e has a positive integer cost `c_e` and a starting vertex `s\in V` . Design an `O(V + E)` algorithm that marks all vertices reachable from `s` using a path (not necessarily a simple path) with the total cost of that path being multiples of 5.

How can I keep track of the total amount of cost of the path that I've already visited? I've been studying about BFS in undirected weighted graphs and made some attempts on using it here, but most of the BFS references focus on finding the shortest path (and not something like **keep it multiple of 5**).

Comment: You need to mark the vertice with the cost of the path it takes to reach that vertex..! Does this sound simpler then the above mentioned question?

Comment: The problem is that you can have more than one path to reach an specific node using the same edge.

Comment: Yes, so one always keeps the value of the shortest path. What is your approach for this scenario?

Comment: I think you can still use usual BFS graph traversal methods here but have a few extra things like saving your path costs in an array/vector to account for the possibility of multiple cost values and adding an extra check to see that the cost of the path is a multiple of 5 before adding the vertex to some sort of "checked" list.

Comment: Are you sure that such an algorithm exists? It seems like an NP problem.

Answer (score 1):

What do you think about the next algorithm?

Let's consider new directed graph based on the source graph. For every vertex `v` from the source graph create `5` new vertexes `v[0], v[1], ..., v[4]` in the new graph corresponding to the modules from the division by `5`. Then, if vertexes `v` and `u` were connected in the source graph by the edge with the weight `w`, add edge between `v[i]` and `u[(i + w) % 5]`, `u[j]` and `v[(j + w) % 5]` in the new graph, where `i = 0..4, j = 0..4`. Then run *BFS* from the `v[0]`, where `v` is the starting vertex in the source graph.

Consider vertexes with the index `0` like `v[0]`. Each of them corresponding to the path of the length multiple of `5` to the vertex `v` in the source graph. All of such vertexes marked after *BFS* as reachable from the starting vertex form the answer. Total complexity is linear.